# How to receive a file in PHP and send it to another API as a file?

Tags: javascript, php, api

I have two different APIs for my website. One is the main API which does all the processing, saving and validation. The other is just a proxy to my main API to get around cross domain errors.

I am trying to post an image as a file to my proxy domain and then pass that same image as a file again to my main API.

Here is my Javascript calling my API

```
function saveImage () {
    //Getting my image as base64. Works perfectly since I can log it and view it in a new window
    var imageEncoded = postImgUpload.getImageDataURl();

    var resourceApiData = {
        type: 1,
        content: imageEncoded
    };

    apiService.createNewResource(resourceApiData);
}

//My function inside 'apiService'
createNewResource: function(apiData) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "data:image/png;base64," + apiData.content;

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("type", apiData.type);
    formData.append("content", image);

    var apiRequest = postApiRoot + "createNewResource";

    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: apiRequest,
        data: apiData,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        responseType: 'json'
    });
},
```

Here is my PHP processing the passed up data and sending it to my main API

```
private function createNewResource() {
    $content = $_FILES['content']['tmp_name'];
    $type = "image";

    $data = array(
      'type' => $type,
      'content' => $content
    );

    $this->runApiCall($url, true, "POST", $data, false);
}
```

The `runApiCall` method definitely works since I am currently using it for all other API calls on my site. This is the only one that is giving me a `422 Unprocessable Entity` response from my main API.

If I go into POSTman and post my image as a file directly to my main API, it works with no problem at all.

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Here is my `runApiCall` method:

```
private function runApiCall($url, $returnTransfer, $method, $postData, $header) {
    $url = "example.org/" . $url;

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, $returnTransfer);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
    if($method === 'POST') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    }
    if($method === "DELETE") {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
    }
    if($method === "PUT") {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
    }
    if($postData !== "") {
        if($method === "PUT") {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($postData));
        } else {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
        }
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['nxsession']);
    session_write_close();
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    $this->response($result, $status);
}
```

Comment: So your php method should supply headers and properly formed multipart request body. By the looks of it, it's not really doing that, is it?

Comment: @N.B. - I just added my `runApiCall` method to my question. That does all the processing and passes it on to my main API.

Comment: Where's the boundary? Can you inspect the actual raw body generated this way and compare the differences generated by the JS and PHP? That's the easiest way to determine where the gremlin is.

Comment: Sorry, not too sure what you mean. It is a RESTful API service. Unable to inspect anything that's generated from it. All I know is that I am posting up a base64 encoded image and I am trying to then pass that same file to my main API. I believe that I am not passing it properly due to my `422` error.

Answer (score 0):

If both API's have access to the same file system, you could have the first API save the file on the file system and then just pass along the full path to the file to the second API.

Comment: Unfortunately they do not. They are on completely different servers.

Comment: How do you do HTTP request to other API?

Comment: @sitnarf - My `runApiCall` method uses PHP's cURL. Would you like me to make an edit to my question to include that method?

Answer (score 0):

Depends how did you implemented runApiCall, but it needs to append whole data but you are passing just temporally path to file uploaded to the server.

Look at: http://php.net/manual/en/class.httprequest.php and http://php.net/manual/en/httprequest.addpostfile.php

**Update** (reaction to posted curl implementation)

Ok, you are using curl, so it should be easy. Just perpend "@" before actual path. See https://coderwall.com/p/fck2ta/how-to-send-files-via-curl-in-php.

**Update** (added edited code)

```
private function createNewResource() {
    $content = "@".$_FILES['content']['tmp_name'];
    $type = "image";

    $data = array(
      'type' => $type,
      'content' => $content
    );

    $this->runApiCall($url, true, "POST", $data, false);
}
```

Comment: Just posted my `runAPiCall` method.

Comment: The `addPostFile` sounds interesting. Not too much documentation on it though. Any chance of a quick example?

Comment: Still getting an `Unprocessable Entity` error unfortunately. Do you think it is perhaps the way I am passing my image up, since it is base64?

Comment: It shouldn't. it's base64 representation is only on client side. try to display uploaded image or look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: I can easily log the image before posting it to the server, and it seems fine. Maybe appending it to `formData` is incorrect then...

Comment: Just for sure, on the server is it normally formated png/jpeg file? you can for example send back to client and display?

Comment: Instead, what if I sent my raw base64 string to my proxy API, and then used `imagecreatefromstring()` before sending it to my main API?

Comment: What about your $header variable set to false?

Comment: The default is set to false